# typedef for qualified dependent types

Tags: c++, templates, types, typename

I read this nice summary of how the typename keyword in C++ is used: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Still I wonder about a particular example:

```
template<typename T> class Outer{
  public:
    class Inner1{
       T t; 
    };
    class Inner2{
      int t; 
    };
};

template<typename T> void foobar(void)
{
  std::list<Outer<T>::Inner1> l;
}
```

From the text linked above I understand that I need

```
std::list<typename Outer<T>::Inner1> l;
```

since Inner1 is both qualified and dependent.

But: Inner2 also requires a typename which confuses me: 
First, it seems to be pretty clear that Inner2 is a type (well, that's already clear for Inner1). Secondly, Inner2 does not depend on T at all. For all possible Ts, Inner2 will be the same (type)!

Do I need typedef as soon as I use a qualified type from inside a template? Whether it depends on the template parameter or not?

Comment: `For all possible Ts, Inner2 will be the same (type)!` - nope, consider class template specialisation.

Answer (score 3):

Your second assumption is wrong. Inner2 *does* depend on T, since each Outer has another Inner2. That becomes clear if you specialize Outer:

```
template<> class Outer<char>{
public:
  class Inner1{
     T t; 
  };
  typedef int Inner2; 
};
```

And even if you don't specialize, `Outer<float>::Inner2` and `Outer<long>::Inner2` may have the same layout, members, names etc, but they are not the same type! Think about access - `Outer<long>::Inner2` has access to `Outer<long>`'s private members, `Outer<float>::Inner2` does not.

In the following specialization Inner2 is not even a type:

```
template<> class Outer<long double>{
public:
  char Inner2(int); 
};
```

Comment: True, I did not consider specializations! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`Outer<T>::Inner2` does depend on the type `T` in the sense that the compiler doesn't know what kind of thing `Inner2` is -- whether it is a type or e.g. a static data member.  So yes, you need to tell the compiler what kind of thing it is by using `typename` here, because the default is to assume that it is a non-type member (e.g. a static data member, a method name, an `enum` value).

(That's true for C++03 -- I'm assuming the rules on this weren't changed in C++11.)